Sheaves on a smooth manifolds and bump functions
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $M$. Clearly if $\mathscr{F}$ is the sheaf of sections of a vector bundle, then every section defined on a compact subset extends to a global section thanks to bump functions, but this is a strong hyphothesis on $\mathscr{F}$.
Are there weaker conditions on $\mathscr{F}$ that allow us to use bump functions in a similar fashion?

The claim about existence of an extension of sections $s\in \mathcal F$ is wrong if taken literally. The correct statement is that if $s\in \mathcal F_U$ then for every compact $K\subset U$ the restriction $s|K$ extends to a global section.

(For a counterexample, $1/x$ is a section of the trivial vector bundle on $\mathbb{R} \setminus 0$ and doesn't extend to a global section of the same bundle on $\mathbb{R}$).

Also, I am unsure what are you looking for but the keywords are "soft sheaf."

@MoisheKohan Thank you for the correction. I've been unrigorous.

I would have told you to look for fine sheaves if you're wanting sheaves that admit partitions of unity.

@TedShifrin Thank you! That's exactly the keyword I was looking for.
